# Java simple maze advice

Tags: java, maze

I have to read a file and solve a maze. What I need to do is to read a maze and print out the solution as follows.

```
  walls marked by '#'
  passages marked by ' '
  path marked by 'X'
  start/end marked by 'S'/'E'

  (x,y) location of the start. (0,0) is upper left and (width-1,height-1) is lower right
  (x,y) location of the end

  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
  1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

  OUTPUT:
  ##########
  #SXX     #
  # #X######
  # #XX    #
  # ##X# ###
  # # X# # #
  # # XX   #
  # ###X####
  # #  XXXE#
  ##########
```

This is just an example to demonstrate what I have to do. Can someone advice me please on what procedure should i follow? I am not asking for any code I just need a starting point to solve this maze.

Do I just need to check the file and replace the '1' with '#' and so on or do I need to use some kind of an algorithm? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Recursion will be the key I guess.

Comment: You will need to iterate line by line through the file, and create a list of a list of rows of game squares.
Finding the route is a different story, you will need an AI pathfinding algorithm if you want this to work with any map you create.

Comment: Without a given Start and End point, there are many solutions.

Comment: You will have to check the file, build some structure to find paths between start and end, then find this path (as Pieter said recursion will help you) and then print the solution.

Comment: Check [Djikstra's algortithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (maybe overkill, better follow Pieter's link)

Comment: Wikipedia has some good explanation of maze solving algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I will try out to make this work thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way your question is posed, it sounds like you are asking us to interpret your specific program requirements. That sounds very off topic, and we are in a worse position than you to decipher that anyway since you have more context than we do, being the person to whom the problem was given.

Your best course of action is to ask whoever gave you the problem (teacher, boss, programming puzzle website, whatever) to elaborate on the problem and requirements descriptions. Hopefully that is possible for you.

If I am misreading your question, and your last paragraph didn't mean what I thought it did and you are really just asking for programming advice, try Googling pathfinding algorithms, especially ones which can return optimal paths. `A*` is one commonly used in video game development.

[Wikipedia A* path-finding algorithm article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: Thank you. Initially I thought this problem is simple to solve but its not. I ll have a look on path-finding thanks for your time!

Comment: @Kristo1990 Since this looks like a homework problem A* is probably overkill.  A simple breadth-first search or "backtracking" algorithm would be easier to implement.

Comment: I ll have a look on what resources I can find and how I can work them out and I ll probably update my question or let you know. Thanks for your interest though :)

Comment: @Kristo1990 On looking again at your question, it looks to me like the section with the 1s and 0s are an example of the text input that your program should expect, with 1s being walls and 0s the space you should move through, and the second version (with #s, Xs, etc.) is an example of what you should output as a solution. However, that begs the question "How do you know from the input where the start/end points are?" Do you get to decide that yourself? Are they always in the corners? Perhaps this is an issue with the problem design? Again, I would ask whoever gave the problem.

Comment: @Aaron hello thank you for your interest I have edited my question.

Comment: @0x5453 When I had computer science homework, it was expected that we implement algorithms like this. It's been a while, but I think I did use A* for homework at least twice. I also implemented perlin-noise algorithm in a graphics programming class, and that is more complicated than A*. It all depends on the class, and it is hard to tell the class level from the question. I was assuming the file I/O was not part of what's being tested but rather is just a simple way to convey the program input. As I suggested, the question asker should know best what the intent is, or if not should ask.

Comment: @0x5453 Then again, the last paragraph of the question, the part that confused me and prompted the first part of my answer, might suggest that this is homework for a lower level class. Perhaps you are right.